# How to find the angle in a triangle when is given measure of a height and a side?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> In a triangle $\triangle{ACB}$, $AC=20\,m$ it is also known $\angle{A}=2\angle{B}$ and the length of the foot of the height drawn from vertex $C$ to point $B$ is equal to $30\,m$ Find angle $C$.

The choices given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{cc}
1.&30^{\circ}\\
2.&60^{\circ}\\
3.&90^{\circ}\\
4.&53^{\circ}\\
5.&75^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

According to the official answers sheet the answer here is choice 3.

I am not sure how to make the right drawing or the interpretation here. Can someone help me with some sketch?

From then on, what is this?. Congruency, any special case of the triangle theorems or what?. This problem belongs to the section about basic relations in triangles thus I believe that it can be solved with those without requiring additional things.

What sort of construction using only euclidean geometry can be done here to solve the problem?

Please help me here, I don't know what to do

Comment: You can check $90^\circ$ is correct with Euclidean geometry  (you get three similar half-equilateral triangles) but to find the answer I suspect you may need trigonometry as they might not be similar without the $20$ and $30$ information

Answer (score 1):

I will help with the drawing, the rest is up to you.

Start with $\triangle ABC$. From $C$ draw the altitude down to point $P$. Label the following quantities:

- $\angle A= 2\theta$
- $\angle B = \theta$
- $AC= 20$ meters
- $PB = 30$ meters (when you make the drawing you will see what that means).

You then have two known right triangles $ACP,BCP$. Use the right triangle laws to render $h$ as two different functions of $\theta$, which must be equal. Then solve the resulting equation for $\theta$.

You must have $\theta<90°$ to fit the geometry ($2\theta<180°$). We have a tighter bound, $\theta<60°$, if we recognize that $\angle C$ measures $180°-3\theta$. You may need a double angle formula with the $2\theta$ angle at $A$.

Good luck!

Comment: Probably worth adding that the answer to the angle at $C$ is $180^\circ - 3\theta$, so you must have $\theta < 60^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Given line segments AC,PB (green,red) are $20,30$ units length respectively. Let angles at vertices B,A be $2 \beta, \beta $ respectively.

HINT:

$$ CP= 30 \tan \beta =30 t = 20 \sin 2 \beta $$

Use sin/tan double angle trig Weierstrass relation

$$3 t= 2 \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \to t( 3t^2-1)=0 $$

$$ t= \tan \beta = ( \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0)$$

Angle at B must be nonzero and also acute (since the triangle also has an angle measuring twice that angle).

Thus angle B is found $30^{\circ}$ , at A is double that, I am sure you can recognize everything else now.

A very narrow  triangle 50 units side at right when triangle ABC shrinks to a straight line can be also drawn, where angles $A,B$ vanish and perpendicular length $PC$ also vanishes. The narrow triangle case can be at first discarded for acute angle case at left.

Comment: You blew my cover!

Comment: OP's " length of the foot of the height drawn from vertex C to point B" could have been simply put " perpendicular from C to AB".  After figuring it out found your helpful explanation to draw the rough sketch.